# PDF file problem in browser

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, pdf-generation, mime-types

When I click on pdf file (this file was generated by coldfusion previously) link, it opens in same browser(same like inline).

But what I want is, when I click on link, browser should ask "do you want save this file" window box.

I have one more pdf file which do the same thing what I want. Anybody knows why two pdf file works different way?

```
<a href="./test.pdf">click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to force a file to be downloaded rather than displayed in the browser, you can do so by adding a `Content-Disposition` header, like

```
<cfheader  NAME="Content-Disposition" VALUE="attachment">
```

However, that assumes that you'll be passing the PDF through CF.  If you want your web server to serve it directly, you'll have to have it apply a similar header.  If you do want to use CF, you can do something like

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#fileName#" />
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#filepath#" />
```

but be VERY SURE that there is no way for a user to request something other than the PDF through this mechanism, or you've opened yourself up to a trivial [Insecure Direct Object Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4) vulnerability.